# Only prints out last line to the text file and not the rest in java

Tags: java, text-files

I am trying to print a file to the text file. Although I have managed to make it work, it only prints out the last line that is printed on the console. E.g. My console has around 8000 lines but it only prints out the last line in the text file, and I want to print all the lines into the text file. 
This is the code:

```
       try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("JDT.txt"));
        Writer output = null;
        File file = new File("output.txt");
        output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));


        String line = reader.readLine();
        int count=0;
        while(line !=null)
        {
            for(int i = 0 ; i<faults.length;i++){
                if(line.contains(faults[i]))
                    System.out.println(line);
                count++; 
                output.write(line +"Total: "+count);
                //System.out.println("File Written");
        }
            line=reader.readLine();
            }                  
        System.out.println("Printed Lines =" +count); 
                   output.close();     
        }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }       
}
    }
```

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Why are you reopening the file after each line?

Comment: Long answer very short - you are creating a new file "output.txt" on everyline you read in.

Comment: I placed the `Writer output = null; File file = new File("output.txt"); output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));` after BufferReader. I still have the same problem.

Comment: Post the new edited code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place these lines before the beginning of the `while` loop.

```
Writer output = null;
File file = new File("output.txt");
output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
```

And close the `Writer` after while loop exits.

```
output.close();
```

Also the statement `output.write(line +"Total: "+count);` is trying to write every line at the end of another, resulting in one big line of output. Replace it with:

```
output.write(line + "Total: " + count + "\n");
```

This should result in each line getting printed on a new line.

Not sure if it's expected but in your code `output.write` might get executed multiple times for the same line depending on the length of your `faults` variable. This will result in same line getting printed more than once.

If the length of the `faults` is `n` the `write` will be called `n` times for the same `line`.

I think you need this:

```
while (line != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < faults.length; i++) {
        if (line.contains(faults[i])) {
            count++;
            output.write(line + "Total: " + count + "\n");
            System.out.println(line);
            break;
        }
    }
    // System.out.println("File Written");
    line = reader.readLine();
}
```

Comment: I did, it still prints out one line only in the text file.

Comment: `output.close();` is still inside the loop.

Comment: It works, but all the sentences are in one line, is there any way in which I could print the sentences in a new lines?

Comment: It prints in new lines now, but it's printing the same sentence 20 times.

Comment: The faults is an array, which is looking for keywords from a text file then printing the text file out. Is there any way I could change this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24926/discussion-between-nishant-shreshth-and-vruti-d)

Answer (score 2):

You are re-creating and overwriting your file in each loop.  Create your file and your `BufferedWriter` before your loops, and close it after your loops finish.

Comment: Yes, I changed it. I still have the same results.

Comment: Place the call to close() _after_ your loops finish.

Comment: It works, but all the sentences are in one line, is there any way in which I could print the sentences in a new lines?

Comment: Call newLine() on your BufferedWriter to start a new line where ever you need.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd put this here for reference. It's just a general approach for copying lines from an input file to an output file.

```
final class Sample
{
   private static final String inputFile = "input_file.txt";
   private static final String outputFile = "output_file.txt";

   public void start()
   {

      BufferedReader bufferedReader;
      BufferedWriter bufferedWriter;
      try
      {
         bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
         bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));
         copyContents(bufferedReader, bufferedWriter);
         bufferedReader.close();
         bufferedWriter.close();
      }
      catch (final IOException e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   private void copyContents(final BufferedReader bufferedReader, final BufferedWriter bufferedWriter)
   {
      try
      {
         String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
         while (null != line)
         {
            bufferedWriter.write(line + '\n');
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
         }
      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```